# Adding a keyword shortcut for Google Maps on Firefox

Tags: google-maps, firefox

I tried to add a keyboard shortcut for searching Google Bookmarks using the option in the right click menu, but when I try to use it, only a blank search box appears. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't recall where I found this solution at the moment (I'll look for it), but the following entry for Location works:

```
http://maps.google.ca/maps?f=q&hl=en&iwloc=addr&q=%s
```

I then added the keyword `map` for this bookmark, and can simply type "map " in Firefox's address bar to see the location in Google Maps.

[EDIT] Lifehacker has [an article](http://lifehacker.com/129658/geek-to-live-fifteen-firefox-quick-searches) on Firefox quick searches complete with a set of bookmarks which includes a Google Maps shortcut.

Also, after some testing, I find the following simpler Location also works:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%s
```

Comment: It is also worth mentioning a nice shortcut from that article for getting the correct URL - right clicking on the search input field and clicking "Add keyword for this search"